# What is the meaning of poolmon negative numbers?

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, driver

I'm using `poolmon` from Win 10 SDK to analyze memory leaks, I'm running it right after the driver was unloaded. My command line is

```
poolmon.exe -s -e -g -r -n poolmondump.txt
```

Argument definition from `poolmon /?`

```
-s                  Display session pool
-n [Logfile]        Take a pool snapshot
                    Logfile maybe specified, default is poolsnap.log
-g [PoolTagFile]    Display driver information using PoolTagFile
                    If PoolTagFile is not specified
                    use 'pooltag.txt' from current directory
-e                  Display totals
-r                  Print memory summary information
```

A piece of output is

```
 Tag  Type     Allocs         Frees    Diff   Bytes    Per Alloc    Mapped_Driver
  SIFP Paged 245366784   2359304  243007480      -1         17       [MyDriver.sys]
  SIFP Nonp          7         7         0       -1         -1       [MyDriver.sys]
```

Sometimes there is negative `Diff`

```
 Tag  Type     Allocs         Frees    Diff   Bytes    Per Alloc    Mapped_Driver
 NweN Paged    529879   4784171  -4254292      -1          1        [MyDriver.sys]
 PBDN Paged        43        66       -23       1          0        [MyDriver.sys]
```

How to understand this? How to deal with this?
I'm trying to rename tags, but every day there is something new.
This occurs only on one of virtual machines used in test setup.

Comment: Is there anything special about that VM? Also, are you sure to restart the machine before you test your driver?

Comment: By looking a the numbers this only means that your driver did free more memory than it did allocate beetween your two measurement points. Allocs is 500K while Frees is 4,7M. Under the assumption that you allocate a sane distribution of evenly sized buffers this will lead to a negative diff.

Answer (score -1):

The [PoolMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon) driver exists in windows, it:

> displays data that the operating system collects about memory
>   allocations from the system paged and nonpaged kernel pools, and the
>   memory pools used for Terminal Services sessions. The data is grouped
>   by pool allocation tag.
>
> Driver developers and testers often use PoolMon to detect memory leaks
>   when they create a new driver, change the driver code, or stress the
>   driver. You can also use PoolMon in each stage of testing to view the
>   driver's patterns of allocation and free operations, and to reveal how
>   much pool memory the driver is using at any given time.

Here are the **commands**:

```
 poolmon [/iTag] [/xTag] [/c [LocalTagFile]] [/g [PoolTagFile]] [/s[TSSessionID]] [ /p | /p /p ] [/e] [/( | /)]  [/t | /a| /f| /d | /b| /m] [/l] [/n [File]] [/? | /h]
```

**Explanation:**

> **Parameters**
>
> /i Displays only the allocations with the specified pool tag. You can
>   have multiple /i parameters in a PoolMon command. Do not type a space
>   between the /i and the Tag argument.
>
> /x Excludes allocations with the specified tag from the display. You
>   can have multiple /x parameters in a PoolMon command. Do not type a
>   space between the /x and the Tag argument.
>
> Tag Specifies a pool tag or pool tag pattern. Pool tags are
>   case-sensitive. The Tag argument can include an asterisk () to
>   represent zero or more instances of any character, or a question mark
>   (?*) to represent one instance of any character. Do not begin a tag
>   with an asterisk.
>
> /c Adds a column to the display (Mapped_Driver) listing the drivers on
>   the local computer that use each pool tag. This feature is supported
>   only on 32-bit versions of Windows.
>
> LocalTagFile Specifies the path and file name of a local tag file, a
>   formatted text file that contains a list of the drivers on the local
>   computer, and the tag values that they assign. This file is the data
>   source for the Mapped_Driver column that appears when you use the /c
>   parameter. The default is localtag.txt.
>
> If you use the /c parameter, but do not specify a value for
>   LocalTagFile, and PoolMon does not find a localtag.txt file in the
>   current directory, PoolMon generates a localtag.txt file by scanning
>   the drivers on the local computer
>   (%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers*.sys) .
>
> /g Adds a column to the display (Mapped_Driver) listing Windows
>   components and commonly used drivers that assign each tag.
>
> PoolTagFile Specifies the path and file name of a formatted text file
>   that lists the names of Windows components and commonly used drivers
>   and the tag values they assign. This file is the data source for the
>   Mapped_Driver column that appears when you use the /g parameter.
>
> The default is pooltag.txt, a file provided by Microsoft. Pooltag.txt
>   is included in the Tools\Other subdirectory of the Windows Driver Kit
>   (WDK).
>
> /s Displays allocations from the Terminal Services session pools.
>
> TSSessionID Displays only allocations from the specified session pool.
>   Do not type a space between the /s parameter and the TSSessionID
>   argument.
>
> /p Displays only allocations from the nonpaged pool.
>
> /p /p Displays only allocations from the paged pool.
>
> /e Displays pool totals. The totals appear at the bottom of the
>   display.
>
> /( or /) Turns on the sort-by-change mode. With /( or /), PoolMon
>   sorts by the change in a value (allocation, free operations, and
>   bytes), instead of the value. The change in each value is displayed in
>   a parentheses after the value.
>
> Use with /a, /f, /b or /m. For example, poolmon /a sorts the display
>   by number of allocations, while poolmon /( /a sorts the display by the
>   change in the number of allocations.
>
> The left parenthesis and right parenthesis characters have the same
>   effect and can be used interchangeably.
>
> /t Sorts alphabetically by tag name. This is the default.
>
> /a Sorts tags by the number of allocations.
>
> /f Sorts tags by the number of free operations.
>
> /d Sorts tags by the difference between bytes allocations and bytes
>   freed.
>
> /b Sorts tags by bytes used.
>
> /m Sorts tags by bytes-per-allocation.
>
> /l Turns highlighting off. By default, PoolMon highlights values that
>   have changed since the last update.
>
> /n Saves a snapshot of the PoolMon output to a file, instead of
>   displaying it in a command window. You can include other command-line
>   parameters to configure the output.
>
> Because the snapshot data is static, the columns that show the change
>   in values in the PoolMon display do not appear in a snapshot file.
>
> File Specifies the name and location of the snapshot file. The default
>   is poolsnap.log.
>
> /? or /h Displays command-line syntax. The /? and /h parameters have
>   the same effect and can be used interchangeably.